# Share pyspark UDF across notebooks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm constantly reusing udfs across ipython notebooks and am trying to figure out if there is some way to share the code.

I'd love to be able to make a file, let's call it `sparktoolz.py`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def myfunc(foo):
    # do stuff to foo
    return transformed_foo

myfunc_udf = F.udf(myfunc, T.SomeType())
```

Then from any given notebook in the same directory as `sparktoolz.py` do something like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sc.addPyFile('sparktoolz.py')

from sparktoolz import myfunc_udf

df = sqlContext.read.parquet('path/to/foo')

stuff = df.select(myfunc_udf(F.col('bar')))
```

Whenever I try something like this, the notebook can find `sparktoolz.py` but gives me an `ImportError: cannot import name myfunc_udf`.

Comment: The method you described usually works in my environment. What spark version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `2.1.0`

Comment: try defining the PYTHONPATH